# Determine index of element in Array.each

Tags: ruby, arrays, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, each

I'm trying to render a bulk of content in rows of three. However, I'm not sure how would I determine the current position of the element using Ruby. This is what I have:

```
<% Animals.each do | animal | %>
    <%= animal.species %>
<% end %>
```

I want to be able to add a `<BR>` or if I was rendering a table a `</TR><TR>` each time we'd hit the third animal in the set. Of course, if the number of elements `nE` isn't divisible by three, then the table would be malformed. I figured by doing a bit of checking after the iteration that I could close it.

But is there a way to get the index of an element that's being iterated over in an `Array.each` method? I have the strong hunch that I could just do the following:

```
<table>
<% Animals.each do | animal | %>
<% if Animals.find_index(animal) / 3 == 0 %>
   <tr>
<% end %>
       <td><%= animal.species %></td>
<% if Animals.find_index(animal) / 3 == 2 %>
   </tr>
<% end %>
</table>
```

My only thing is that `Animal` is a subclass of `ActiveRecord::Base`, so I'm not sure (haven't looked to see) if this would scale well, let alone if each call to `find_index` would be a super intensive method. Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: I'm using Ruby 1.9.3 and according to http://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerable/Enumerator/each_with_index that method isn't available in that version.

However, this would have done the job!

Comment: That method is available. It was only [moved](http://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerable/each_with_index) to a different part of `Enumerable` and since `Array` inherits from it, the method is still available to `Array`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need

```
<% animals = Animals.all %>
<table>
<% animals.in_groups_of(3) do |animal_row| %>
  <tr>
    <% animal_row.compact.each do |animal| %>
      <td><%= render animal %></td>
    <% end %>
  </tr>
<% end %>
</table>
```

Should roughly do the job.

More importantly, I think keeping the Enumerable module's documentation handy has been great for me as a Ruby developer. It is my "favourite" module, and nearly ALWAYS helps me solve tricky problems easily.

Comment: Talk about a quick reply! Thanks!

Comment: Notice how i've used compact in the inner loop. It is critical becase that the last group of 3 may not contain exactly 3 elements (when the total elements are not divisible by 3). The last set is padded with nils and compacting the last sent saves you from nil errors.

Comment: I was going to ask why, but then you read my mind! Thank you again :D

Comment: I pre-empted your question :)

Comment: Not much of a difference but,
   animals.in_groups_of(3, false)   will get rid of the extra nils so you won't have to use compact later.